# PHP Inheritance Override function body

Tags: php, laravel

Hey Guys I have the following Scenario and I can't think of a better way. Maybe you guys can provide a more DRY method

So update method BaseController from Laravel Voyager

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
 // Update Logic Here

 // Redirect Logic

 if (auth()->user()->can('browse', app($dataType->model_name))) {
            $redirect = redirect()->route("voyager.{$dataType->slug}.index");
        } else {
            $redirect = redirect()->back();
        }
}

return $redirect->with([
            'message'    => __('voyager::generic.successfully_updated')." {$dataType->getTranslatedAttribute('display_name_singular')}",
            'alert-type' => 'success',
        ]);
```

Custom Controller that extends the above Base Controller

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
 // Update Logic Copied and Pasted from Base ( Yuck :( )

 // Small Change to the Redirect Logic

 if (auth()->user()->can('browse', app($dataType->model_name))) {
            $redirect = redirect()->route("voyager.{$dataType->slug}.index");
        } else {
             $redirect = redirect()->route("voyager.{$dataType->slug}.show",$id);
        }
}

 return $redirect->with([
                'message'    => __('voyager::generic.successfully_updated')." {$dataType->getTranslatedAttribute('display_name_singular')}",
                'alert-type' => 'success',
            ]);
```

So my question is with the current structure of the Base Controller Is there any other way to override the redirect logic without literally copying and pasting the whole lot of code

- I do not want to edit the BaseController as it will stop me from updating the package

Any thoughts would be great

Cheer

Comment: BaseController is part of a package so it resides in the vendor directory. Therefore any changes will be overwritten by an update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use smaller functions to extract that logic and override it, similar approaches with overriding function through inheritance for changing logic, is used by `Laravel` on `Models` see `getRouteKey()` for example.

In your `BaseController.php`, i would split it up like so.

```
{
     if (auth()->user()->can('browse', app($dataType->model_name))) {
            $redirect = redirect()->route("voyager.{$dataType->slug}.index");
        } else {
            $redirect = $this->browseRedirectLocation();
        }
    }

    return $redirect->with([
        'message' => __('voyager::generic.successfully_updated')." {$dataType->getTranslatedAttribute('display_name_singular')}",
        'alert-type' => 'success',
    ]);
}

protected function browseRedirectLocation() {
{
    return $redirect = redirect()->back();
}
```

Now you should be able to override redirect location in your `CustomController.php`, instead of the whole function in your implementation class. As i could see it was only the redirect that was changed.

```
protected function browseRedirectLocation() {
{
    return redirect()->route("voyager.{$dataType->slug}.show",$id);
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for this but I really did not want to touch the BaseController since it's an external package. This stops me from updating the package.

Comment: But then you have no other options to overwrite it all :) Maybe there is one other option i will do an write up later tonight, but i would just overwrite it all for now

Comment: Yep that's what I thought. No option but to copy and paste the whole lot of code in the function,